# how to dynamically build a list of coroutines for async.gather?

Tags: python-asyncio

at the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#running-tasks-concurrently), we have:

```
async def main():
    await asyncio.gather(
      factorial("A", 2),
      factorial("B", 3),
      factorial("C", 4),
    )
asyncio.run(main())
```

if i wanted the number of coroutines to be parameter of `main`, how it should be implement? I tried

```
async def main(count):
    coroutines = [factorial(str(i),i) for i in range(count)]
    await asyncio.gather(coroutines)
asyncio.run(main(3))
```

but got:

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
sys:1: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'factorial' was never awaited
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at how you're calling `asyncio.gather` in the first example:

```
await asyncio.gather(factorial("A", 2), factorial("B", 3), factorial("C", 4))
```

You're passing three arguments. But in your second example, you're
trying to pass in a single argument (a list of coroutines):

```
await asyncio.gather(coroutines)
```

This isn't an equivalent call. `asyncio.gather` doesn't expect any of
its arguments to be a list, which is why you're getting that
"unhashable type" error message (it's trying to use the argument as a
dictionary key or some other operation that requires a hashable
value).

The equivalent call would be:

```
await asyncio.gather(*coroutines)
```

The `*` operator "unpacks" the list into multiple arguments.

The relevant documentation is [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists).